# Still getting validation error despite using save(commit=False)

Tags: django, django-forms

Model form:

```py
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'category', 'description', 'thumbnail', 'status', 'author']
```

view:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            art = form.save(commit=False)    # Error line
            art.author = request.user
            art.status = 'd'
            art.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:home'))
        elif form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:home'))
        
        return render(request, 'registration/add-update-article.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

If the user is not a superuser, they can not fill some fields in the form so I want to set their values in this view. Isn't `commit=False` supposed to prevent raising validation errors? Why do I still get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `commit` option to `False`, `save()` constructs the Model object, but does not save it to the database. It still preforms validation; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method. You shouldn't try to suppress validation. Instead, figure out what's wrong with the form and set attributes to being not required, having a different maximum value, etc.

However, if what you want is to modify the form fields before saving, you can do this:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            Article.create(**form.cleaned_data, author=request.user, status="d")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:home'))
        elif form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:home'))
        
        return render(request, 'registration/add-update-article.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```